# How to select from which source a software must be installed?

Tags: installation, ppa, software-sources

Here is my problem: I'm using Lucid Lynx and would like to have the latest version of freeciv.

The latest version I can get without adding a PPA is 2.1.10-1, it is in one of the default sources (Don't know which, Universe or Multiverse probably). The current version is 2.3 or something.

I followed instructions on how to get up to date versions by adding `ppa:kgoetz/ppa` to the list of the sources. No problem here.

After reloading the sources, the version I can install is still the 2.1.10-1, the one from official sources. From the Synaptic Package Manager, I could "Force the version", but the item is disabled in the menu.

My question is: is there a way to override or select a particular source when installing a software?

This question is, of course, not limited to my particular case but to a global use of software sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kgoetz PPA doesnt have a version of FreeCiv for Lucid.

Probably the best source of opensource Lucid games - and the latest version of FreeCiv is playdeb.net.

They have packaged v2.3.1 for Lucid - [download links](http://www.playdeb.net/software/FreeCiv)

[image]

Its probably best to stick with the "stable" versions in the repository.  However, I've found that the playdeb.net games are actually packaged very well - and the developers behind the site are very responsive to any issues and if you contact them, usually turn around a packaging fix very quickly.

You are correct to use synaptic manager to force versions - I rarely use this option unless there is a package issue with the latest update.

Obviously, if there isnt a newer version available either through PPAs or the standard repositories - you will not be able to force versions and hence the menu option would be greyed out/disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked perfectly. Thanks also for this great website! I didn't know it.

Answer (score 0):

`ppa:kgoetz/ppa` doesn't have a package for freeciv, and it doesn't have packages for Lucid at all (but only packages for `tweepy` and `creepy`, both only for Maverick), see https://launchpad.net/~kgoetz/+archive/ppa/+packages). So adding it doesn't get you any new software.

In general the package manager always gets you the latest packages that available for your distribution in your software sources